# Generate fullstack application using yeoman fullstack

Tags: angularjs, node.js, bower, angular-fullstack

I want to generate a fullstack application and I was thinking of using a yeoman generator. I tried using the latest version of yeoman fullstack generator and I generated the project but I don't understand very well the structure of the project.

I noticed that this project doesn't use bower and I don't know how to manage dependecies from other components. Can you explain to me how this project works?

If you cannot explain this to me, I would like a project with bower so can you tell me which is the latest version of angular fullstack that still uses bower?

Best regarts.

Comment: this *feels like* a request for a 3rd party library or tutorial in using a 3rd party library, which is off topic here.

Comment: First of all I want to find the last version of angular fullstack that contains bower.

Comment: a simple search of the repository returns : https://github.com/angular-fullstack/generator-angular-fullstack/blob/94eace310b5d98ec2cf044b27dd0767728856d84/CHANGELOG.md#webpack/

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know how to find this information. And if you could also explain to me why they gave up on bower it would be a bonus

Comment: since webpack shares the same modules client side and server side and has ES6 support, it's one of the new emergent standards.